# Rails: Order Model by sum of stats in child model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, associations

I have a Player model, a Player model has many PlayerStats.

If I wanted to get a Player's total goals, I'd use:

```
@player.player_stats.sum(:goals)
```

How can I use the Player model to retrieve a list of the players with the most goals in the controller?

I was thinking something like:

```
@players = Player.order(:goals).limit(7)
```

but I can't do that because a Player doesn't have goals directly, it has many PlayerStats which contain their goals.

NOTE: I'm using a mySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should do it:

```
Player
  .joins(:player_stats)
  .group('player_stats.id')
  .order('SUM(player_stats.goals) DESC')
  .limit(7)
```

You can use scope in your case:

```
class Player
  scope :by_goals, lambda {
    joins(:player_stats).group('players.id').order('SUM(player_stats.goals) DESC')
  }
end
```

and in controller:

```
Player.by_goals.limit(7)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: Will do! I was actually just doing some more testing and it looks like it's repeating players in the hash. As in, the player with the most goals and second most goals is always the same player instance. Not sure why it's doing that because after the first two it's working correctly.

Comment: Actually it's not always the first two, just ran it again and it doesn't seem to be ordering them properly. Currently there are 6 players, and when I use limit(6) is doesn't always get 6 unique players.

Comment: I changed it to includes, and in the show.html.er where I'm iterating through the @players hash, I get this error: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'player_stats.id' in 'group statement': SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` GROUP BY player_stats.id ORDER BY SUM(player_stats.goals) DESC

Comment: The also generated an error when I go to loop through in the show.html.erb. This is that error: Mysql2::Error: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, contains aggregate function; this is incompatible with DISTINCT: SELECT DISTINCT `players`.* FROM `players` INNER JOIN `player_stats` ON `player_stats`.`player_id` = `players`.`id` GROUP BY player_stats.id ORDER BY SUM(player_stats.goals) DESC

Comment: @Fianite well that's interesting.. Two more options. 1) change `distinct` to `uniq`. 2) change `distinct` to `group('players.id')`

Comment: First option still raised an error, second didn't raise an error but still has the same problem. The first two players in the hash have the same ID.

Comment: @Fianite what if you change `.group('player_stats.id')` to `.group('players.id')`? It's a bit hard to guess remotely without a chance to debug.. :)

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick, thanks for all the help despite not being to actually see what I'm working with. :)

Comment: @Fianite no probs, it's actually me who just made a typo from the beginning and did not see it for such a long time :)